# Diagnose Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I am unable to use Remote Desktop to access my PC from a different machine. When I do RDP from my own network it asks for my login credentials (good). But when I try it from the outside network, it times out. I used this [Port Forwarding Tester](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to ensure port 3389 is being forwarded and I went into Windows Firewall to allow anything related to port 3389.

Is there any other thing I can do to diagnose this?

Edit: I am running RDP 6.3.9600 and Windows 7.

Comment: what versions of RDP are installed, what are the OS's involved?

Comment: RDP 6.3.9600, Windows 7 on both machines

Comment: Update your question with the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely means that the port forwarding machine / router is not actually visible to you (timeout = I can't reach the machine you are telling me to or it is not responding).

Did you verify that you can actually get to the machine that does the port forwarding (even in a browser or via Telnet) on a different port or do you have a way to monitor the activity there in a different way?

/cd

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is update both PC's to RDP version 8.1

[Download from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2923545)

This article describes an update for the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) 8.1 in Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. This update package provides the following improvements:

Fixes connection reliability issues.

Provides better error messages for connection failures.

Resolves a time-out issue in which a connection to a virtual machine hosted in

Microsoft Azure disconnects after being idle for more than 4 minutes and requires re-authentication.

Comment: I got "Update for Windows is already installed on this computer" on both computers